# How to get a sha256 as an `&[u8; 32]`?

Tags: rust, slice, sha256

The [`sha256::digest()` function](https://docs.rs/sha256/latest/sha256/index.html) returns a `String`.

I can turn this into a `[u8; 32]` myself, but it seems wasteful for this crate to turn bytes into a hex string, and for me to then turn this hex string back into bytes.

How can I get the sha256 digest of a `[u8]` slice as an `&[u8; 32]`, or at worst, as an `&[u8]`?

Comment: You may prefer the [`hmac_sha256` crate](https://docs.rs/hmac-sha256/latest/hmac_sha256/struct.Hash.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the source code of the `sha256` crate, a few layers below that interface, there is a code equivalent to this:

```
use sha2::{Digest, Sha256};

impl sha256 {
    fn digest(data: &[u8]) -> String {
        hex::encode(Sha256::digest(data))
    }
}
```

So I think your solution is to just use the [`sha2::Sha256`](https://docs.rs/sha2/0.10.7/sha2/type.Sha256.html)::[`digest()`](https://docs.rs/sha2/0.10.7/sha2/type.Sha256.html) function directly. (The documentation is a bit messy because of the heave use of generics of the `sha2` crate, but I think that it is more or less equivalent to what you need, except that it returns a [`GenericArray<u8, 32>`](https://docs.rs/generic-array/latest/generic_array/struct.GenericArray.html) instead of a `[u8; 32]`, but it should behave basically the same, and can be converted into an array if needed with `try_into().unwrap()`.

Comment: Thanks, `let hash: [u8;32] = sha2::Sha256::digest(ks).into();` did the job.